# Динамическое добавление данных в QListWidget

Tags: python, pyqt5, сигналы-слоты, qtimer, qlistwidget

Такая проблема возникла, делаю свой виджет, который будет добавляться динамически в `QListWidget`, если сделать статический вывод:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtGui, QtWidgets

class QCustomQWidget (QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__ (self, parent = None):
        super(QCustomQWidget, self).__init__(parent)
        self.textQVBoxLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.textUpQLabel    = QtWidgets.QLabel()
        self.textDownQLabel  = QtWidgets.QLabel()
        self.textQVBoxLayout.addWidget(self.textUpQLabel)
        self.textQVBoxLayout.addWidget(self.textDownQLabel)
        self.allQHBoxLayout  = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.iconQLabel      = QtWidgets.QLabel()
        self.allQHBoxLayout.addWidget(self.iconQLabel, 0)
        self.allQHBoxLayout.addLayout(self.textQVBoxLayout, 1)
        self.setLayout(self.allQHBoxLayout)

    def setTextUp (self, text):
        self.textUpQLabel.setText(text)

    def setTextDown (self, text):
        self.textDownQLabel.setText(text)

    def setIcon (self, imagePath):
        self.iconQLabel.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(imagePath))

class exampleQMainWindow (QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__ (self):
        super(exampleQMainWindow, self).__init__()
        self.myQListWidget = QtWidgets.QListWidget(self)
        for index, name, icon in [
            ('No.1', 'Андрей',  'icon.png'),
            ('No.2', 'Петя', 'icon.png'),
            ('No.3', 'Вася',  'icon.png')]:
            myQCustomQWidget = QCustomQWidget()
            myQCustomQWidget.setTextUp(index)
            myQCustomQWidget.setTextDown(name)
            myQCustomQWidget.setIcon(icon)
            myQListWidgetItem = QtWidgets.QListWidgetItem(self.myQListWidget)
            myQListWidgetItem.setSizeHint(myQCustomQWidget.sizeHint())
            self.myQListWidget.addItem(myQListWidgetItem)
            self.myQListWidget.setItemWidget(myQListWidgetItem, myQCustomQWidget)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.myQListWidget)

app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
window = exampleQMainWindow()
window.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

то всё прекрасно выводится:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

> но если попытаться допустим запустить цикл:

---

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtGui, QtWidgets
import time

class QCustomQWidget (QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__ (self, parent = None):
        super(QCustomQWidget, self).__init__(parent)
        self.textQVBoxLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.textUpQLabel    = QtWidgets.QLabel()
        self.textDownQLabel  = QtWidgets.QLabel()
        self.textQVBoxLayout.addWidget(self.textUpQLabel)
        self.textQVBoxLayout.addWidget(self.textDownQLabel)
        self.allQHBoxLayout  = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.file_iconQLabel      = QtWidgets.QLabel()
        self.capture_iconQLabel = QtWidgets.QLabel()
        self.file_iconQLabel.setMinimumSize(80, 80)
        self.file_iconQLabel.setMaximumSize(80, 80)
        self.capture_iconQLabel.setMinimumSize(80, 80)
        self.capture_iconQLabel.setMaximumSize(80, 80)
        self.allQHBoxLayout.addWidget(self.file_iconQLabel, 0)
        self.allQHBoxLayout.addWidget(self.capture_iconQLabel, 0)
        self.allQHBoxLayout.addLayout(self.textQVBoxLayout, 1)
        self.setLayout(self.allQHBoxLayout)


    def setTextUp (self, text):
        self.textUpQLabel.setText(text)

    def setTextDown (self, text):
        self.textDownQLabel.setText(text)

    def setFileIcon (self, imagePath):
        self.file_iconQLabel.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(imagePath))
        
    def setCaptureIcon (self, imagePath):
        self.capture_iconQLabel.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(imagePath))
        

class exampleQMainWindow (QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__ (self):
        super(exampleQMainWindow, self).__init__()
        self.myQListWidget = QtWidgets.QListWidget(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.myQListWidget)
        while True:
            index = "1"
            name = "Петя"
            file_icon = "faces/924.jpg"
            capture_icon = "faces/924.jpg"
            myQCustomQWidget = QCustomQWidget()
            myQCustomQWidget.setTextUp(index)
            myQCustomQWidget.setTextDown(name)
            myQCustomQWidget.setFileIcon(file_icon)
            myQCustomQWidget.setCaptureIcon(capture_icon)
            myQListWidgetItem = QtWidgets.QListWidgetItem(self.myQListWidget)
            myQListWidgetItem.setSizeHint(myQCustomQWidget.sizeHint())
            self.myQListWidget.addItem(myQListWidgetItem)
            self.myQListWidget.setItemWidget(myQListWidgetItem, myQCustomQWidget)
            time.sleep(2)
        
    def run():
        app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
        window = exampleQMainWindow()
        window.show()
        app.exec_()
        
if __name__ == "__main__":
    exampleQMainWindow.run()
```

---

> тогда программа просто не запускается, подскажите как всё таки добавлять динамически строки с моим виджетом в `QListWidget`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ваша программа очень даже запускается, но вы заходите в бесконечный цикл, из которого не выхода. Формирование экземпляра класса `window = ExampleQMainWindow()` никогда не закончится и до `window.show()` дело не доходит.

Если вам надо добавлять строки в QListWidget, это должно делаться в отдельном методе (например: `def dynamicListWidget(self)`), а этот метод должен быть вызван в результате какого-то события. Это событие и выше указанный метод связываются сигналом.

Для демонстрации выше сказанного проще всего воспользоваться классом `QtCore.QTimer предоставляет повторяющиеся single-shot таймер`.

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtGui, QtWidgets

# Класс QtCore.QTimer предоставляет повторяющиеся single-shot таймер.
# http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtimer.html
from PyQt5.QtCore import QTimer
#import time

class QCustomQWidget (QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__ (self, parent = None):
        super(QCustomQWidget, self).__init__(parent)
        self.textQVBoxLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.textUpQLabel    = QtWidgets.QLabel()
        self.textDownQLabel  = QtWidgets.QLabel()
        self.textQVBoxLayout.addWidget(self.textUpQLabel)
        self.textQVBoxLayout.addWidget(self.textDownQLabel)

        self.allQHBoxLayout     = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.file_iconQLabel    = QtWidgets.QLabel()
        self.capture_iconQLabel = QtWidgets.QLabel()
        self.file_iconQLabel.setMinimumSize(80, 80)
        self.file_iconQLabel.setMaximumSize(80, 80)
        self.capture_iconQLabel.setMinimumSize(80, 80)
        self.capture_iconQLabel.setMaximumSize(80, 80)
        self.allQHBoxLayout.addWidget(self.file_iconQLabel, 0)
        self.allQHBoxLayout.addWidget(self.capture_iconQLabel, 0)
        self.allQHBoxLayout.addLayout(self.textQVBoxLayout, 1)
        self.setLayout(self.allQHBoxLayout)


    def setTextUp (self, text):
        self.textUpQLabel.setText(text)

    def setTextDown (self, text):
        self.textDownQLabel.setText(text)

    def setFileIcon (self, imagePath):
        self.file_iconQLabel.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(imagePath))

    def setCaptureIcon (self, imagePath):
        self.capture_iconQLabel.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(imagePath))


class ExampleQMainWindow (QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__ (self):
        super(ExampleQMainWindow, self).__init__()
        self.setGeometry(600, 70, 300, 650)
        self.index = 1

        self.myQListWidget = QtWidgets.QListWidget(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.myQListWidget)

        self.dynamicListWidget()

        self.timer = QTimer()
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.dynamicListWidget)
        self.timer.start(2000)

    def dynamicListWidget(self):
            name = "Петя-Динамик"
            file_icon    = "E:/_Qt/img/avatar2.jpeg" #"faces/924.jpg"
            capture_icon = "E:/_Qt/img/avatar2.jpeg" #"faces/924.jpg"
            myQCustomQWidget = QCustomQWidget()
            myQCustomQWidget.setTextUp(str(self.index))
            myQCustomQWidget.setTextDown(name)
            myQCustomQWidget.setFileIcon(file_icon)
            myQCustomQWidget.setCaptureIcon(capture_icon)
            myQListWidgetItem = QtWidgets.QListWidgetItem(self.myQListWidget)
            myQListWidgetItem.setSizeHint(myQCustomQWidget.sizeHint())
            self.myQListWidget.addItem(myQListWidgetItem)
            self.myQListWidget.setItemWidget(myQListWidgetItem, myQCustomQWidget)

            self.index += 1

            if self.index == 7:
                self.timer.stop()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app    = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
    window = ExampleQMainWindow()
    window.show()
    app.exec_()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ, сейчас попробую, цикл был указан как бы для понимания, добавление будет происходить не в цикле, а когда из кадра будет захвачено лицо.

Comment: Всё получилось! Спасибо вам большое добрый человек! :)